# What is the type of a?

Tags: haskell

I have the following statement:

```
Prelude> :t error "Hello"
error "Hello" :: a
```

that I would like to know, what is the type of `a`?

Comment: `a` is the type.

Comment: It can be any type, the `error` has type `error :: String -> a`, so you can use it for any expression.

Comment: Pfft, amateurs. The type of `a` is `TYPE 'LiftedRep`.

Comment: @DanielWagner did you expect that to mean anything to OP? Because I don't suspect it does.

Comment: @DanielWagner If you want to be pedantic, wouldn't you have to say "the **kind** of `a`"?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica [Nope!](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeInType)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` is a type variable, one that could be unified with *any* concrete type you like. Want to add `error "Hello"` to an `Integer`? OK.

```
> :t error "Hello" + (3 :: Integer)
error "Hello" + (3 :: Integer) :: Integer
```

Want to prepend a `Maybe Char` value? No problem.

```
> :t Just 'c' : error "Hello"
Just 'c' : error "Hello" :: [Maybe Char]
```

Whatever you want `a` to be, `error` will tell you it can return a value of that type.

---

Of course, this is a moot point, because `error` will never actually return.

```
> error "Hello" + (3 :: Integer)
*** Exception: Hello
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at <interactive>:3:1 in interactive:Ghci1

> Just 'c' : error "Hello"
[Just 'c'*** Exception: Hello
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at <interactive>:4:12 in interactive:Ghci1
```

Especially in the last one: `ghci` starts to output a value of type `[Maybe Char]`, and succeeds at outputting the first element, because `(:)` is non-strict in its second element. Not until an attempt is actually made to get the second value does `error "Hello"` get evaluated and its "bluff" is called. Rather than being able to match it against either `[]` or `(:)`, a runtime exception occurs.

Answer (score 6):

`a` is the type; that is, `error "Hello"` can be *any* type, and GHCi can't tell you what specific type it should be without more context.

Values of type `a` (with no constraints, not e.g. `Eq a => a`) are called "bottom values," and they arise as exceptional states or certain non-terminating expressions. Perhaps the best-known bottom value is `Prelude.undefined`:

```
undefined :: a
```

Trying to examine this value will throw

```
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

Likewise, your `error "Hello"` will throw

```
*** Exception: Hello
```

(Thus `undefined` is just `error "Prelude.undefined"`.) An example of a nonterminating expression with type `a` is:

```
let q = q in q
:t q
q :: a
```

And attempting to evaluate that expression will enter an infinite loop.